# Adding Experience and education references to CV?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

When editing a CV on CSO, there's no section to add references to your experience or education - usually containing a mailing address and a phone number.

I have a number of previous employers and tutors - it would be valuable for this reference information to allow a potential employer to contact my previous employers.

Are there any plans for this to be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is far more common on CVs outside the US. For various and sundry reasons related to the litigious American legal system, it is rare inside the US.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer Joel - the majority of UK CVs contain this information off-the-bat.

Comment: I live in the UK, but don't put reference on my CV, as I don't what lots of peole phoneing them up.  I will provide the reference when requested.

Comment: "References available by request" is standard in NA, and is generally implied if not included explicitly.  I always want to know in advance when my references are going to be called (mainly so I can warn them in advance, and to confirm that they're still okay with being contacted.)

Comment: Increasingly the "various and sundry reasons related to the litigious ... legal system" also apply in the UK.  Many companies now instruct people to simply confirm the employment period and offer no more expansion.  For years people were recommended to say nothing negative - these days nothing positive either - all for fear of litigation.

Answer (score 4):

Checking of references seems like something that should be done after contact has been established, not just when an employer first looks at a CV.  So why have it in this?

Keep in mind that your references aren't going to want to field a large number of calls; but don't mind talking to someone that you are seriously interested in and is seriously interested in you.

Comment: In which case - what about a small checkbox saying: 
References available upon request?

Comment: Daniel, when is that ever *not* true?

Comment: @Craig - because sometimes you don't have them available (your ex-boss left the job and moved, no contact info), or don't want to make them available (your entire team was disbanded because new big boss came in and decided to replace you with a squadron of winged outsourced monkeys). Or you worked for NSA (legally not allowed to give out contact info).

Comment: OK, then maybe the checkbox should say, "The dog ate my references." Those few sorry souls unable to come up with a single reference for themselves, ever, can check it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first look at cv, checking references are time-consuming. Before interview, recruiters ask each applicant to fill and sign a release form permitting them to ask detailed questions. If they are interested in you after interview, they proceed screening process.

The offer of employment made is usually subject to satisfactory pre-employment screening. It involves previous employment and education verification, professional references and also memberships.